# Необходимо вывести уникальные элементы массивов со словарям python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

есть два массива

```
ar1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":4},{"a":6, "b":123, "c":5},{"a":123, "b":54, "c":768}]
ar2 = [{"a":6, "b":435, "c":123},{"a":1, "b":435, "c":123}]
```

Необходимо вернуть разницу массивов **ar1** и **ar2** по ключу **a** т.е. те словари значения **a** которых уникальны для обоих массивов

В данном примере мне необходимо что бы в результате было что то вроде такого [{"a":123, "b":54, "c":768}] т.к. только у этого словаря ключ a уникален

Циклом не подходит, т.к. важна производительность

Comment: какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: массив со словарями

Comment: `res = [{}]` готово, а если серьёзно то какие именно словари?

Comment: В данном примере мне необходимо что бы в результате было что то вроде такого `[{"a":123, "b":54, "c":768}]`  т.к. только  у этого словаря ключ a уникален

Comment: `Циклом не подходит, т.к. важна производительность` а каким образом цикл влияет на производительность ?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч как я понимаю, здесь не обойтись без вложенных циклов, а в этот алгоритм будут передаваться большие массивы и нужно что бы он отрабатывал быстро

Answer (score 4):

Вообще без циклов не выйдет - вам же нужно будет хотя бы один раз пройти по каждому списку. Могу предложить такое решение - по одному проходу по каждому из списков словарей и потом моментальный вывод подходящих элементов, для чего я использую два множества и словарь, т.е. коллекции с моментальным доступом.

```
ar1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":4},{"a":6, "b":123, "c":5},{"a":123, "b":54, "c":768}]
ar2 = [{"a":6, "b":435, "c":123},{"a":1, "b":435, "c":123}]

set1 = set()
set2 = set()
dict_all = dict()

for d in ar1:
    k = d["a"]
    set1.add(k)
    dict_all[k] = d
    
for d in ar2:
    k = d["a"]
    set2.add(k)
    dict_all[k] = d

for k in set1.symmetric_difference(set2):
    print(dict_all[k])

# {'a': 123, 'b': 54, 'c': 768}
```

Таким образом, я внутри циклов сразу создаю словарь с ключом - значением `a` из словаря, и значением - собственно этим словарём. Повторяющиеся ключи затирают друг друга, но это не важно в данном случае (если важно - можно вести список и добавлять в него все словари, для этого удобно использовать `defaultdict`). В конце берётся симметричная разность множеств значений ключа `a` из обоих списков и выводятся соответствующие словари с помощью предварительно заполненного мной словаря, чтобы второй раз не бежать по спискам.

Повторного хранения данных при этом не будет - в моём словаре хранятся только ключи и ссылки на словари из списков, которые и так хранятся в памяти. Так что дополнительный расход памяти - на ключи и ссылки, но не на сами словари.